# Why UIPickerView is semi transparent

Tags: ios, uipickerview, opacity, transparent, alpha

Why `UIPickerView` is not %100 opaque?
When I set text color to white and put UIPickerView on a red background, the UIPickerView items have a **reddish white** text color.

I tried custom views using `viewForRow`, but still no effect.

How can I set opacity of UIPickerView to %100?
In IB it's alpha is 1 but actually in runtime it isn't

Comment: May it cover another semitransparent View, that is composed at runtime? Or you could post a code of your data source and delegate methods.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this delegate and make your own customize view and return it.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:
```

Comment: Customize view has no effect, it will be transparent too, even if you set `alpha` to 2