# UIPickerView Image Quality Loss

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I just set up a UIPickerView with different images in each row using

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let rowImg = UIImage(named: array[row] + ".png")

    let rowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:60,height:60))
    rowView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: rowImg!)
    return rowView
}
```

I noticed that the image was softened more than I like and the color went from a sharp red to almost a soft red-orange. Anyway around this?

Comment: Do you really mean to set the image as a pattern image for the view's background color? Or do you really just want to show each image as a normal image?

Comment: I see the same thing. I can't figure out what causes it and I don't understand why I can't find any complaints about it. It's as if a lowered `alpha` is being added to the view.

Comment: Okay, I finally found another complaint about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39325827/341994